# Finding first, second and third derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I find the first, second and third derivatives of the function

$$f(x)=f\left(f(x)f\left(x^2\right)\right)\ ?$$

Comment: Finding the set of infinitely differentiable funtions $f(x)$ that satisfy your equation is a nice (but highly non-trivial) problem.  The solutions I can see are $f(x) = C$ where $C$ is any constant, and $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$.  Since these have very different derivatives, I guess the "answer" to the problem posed is the ugly mess outlined by Elliot.

Comment: In other words: are you sure this is what you want to ask? Adding some motivation would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f'\left(f(x)f(x^2)\right)\cdot (f(x)'f(x^2)+2xf(x)f'(x^2)) $$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)=
\frac{d}{dx}f'\left(f(x)f(x^2)\right)\cdot (f(x)'f(x^2)+2xf(x)f'(x^2))
=f''\left(f(x)f(x^2)\right)\cdot (f(x)'f(x^2)+2xf(x)f'(x^2))^2+ 
f'\left(f(x)f(x^2)\right)\cdot (f(x)''f(x^2)+2xf(x)'f'(x^2)+2f(x)f'(x^2)
+2xf'(x)f'(x^2)+4x^2f(x)f''(x^2))
$$

$$\frac{d^3}{dx^3}f(x)=
f^{(3)}\left(f(x) f\left(x^2\right)\right) \left(f\left(x^2\right) f'(x)+2 x f(x) f'\left(x^2\right)\right)^3+3 \left(f\left(x^2\right) f'(x)+2 x f(x) f'\left(x^2\right)\right) f''\left(f(x) f\left(x^2\right)\right) \left(f\left(x^2\right) f''(x)+4 x f'(x) f'\left(x^2\right)+2 f(x) \left(2 x^2 f''\left(x^2\right)+f'\left(x^2\right)\right)\right)+f'\left(f(x) f\left(x^2\right)\right) \left(f\left(x^2\right) f^{(3)}(x)+8 x^3 f(x) f^{(3)}\left(x^2\right)+12 x f(x) f''\left(x^2\right)+6 x f'\left(x^2\right) f''(x)+6 f'(x) \left(2 x^2 f''\left(x^2\right)+f'\left(x^2\right)\right)\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the chain rule and product rule:

$f'(x)=\color{red}{f'(f(x)f(x^2))}\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)f(x^2))}$

$=\color{red}{f'(f(x)f(x^2))}\color{blue}{(f'(x)f(x^2)+2xf(x)f'(x^2))}$

etc. It won't be pretty, however.